# Replace string part with regex pattern

Tags: java, regex

I  would like to replace the following string.

```
img/s/430x250/
```

The problem is there are variations, like:

```
img/s/265x200/
```

or:

```
img/s/110x73/
```

So I would like to replace this part in whole, but the numbers are changeable, so how could I make a pattern that replaces it from a string?

Comment: What is your code that is failing? Please share.

Comment: What makes you think this could be possible? In other words: you are just dropping a requirement here; but we expect you to show us that you tried solving the problem yourself.

Comment: Did you read the documentation for `Pattern`? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html (particularly the section on "Predefined character classes")

Comment: Expected input/output, what you've tried, etc.

Comment: Are you trying to match this: "img/s/[some_number]x[some_other_number]/"?

Comment: What language are you using? Regex engine implementation differs from environment to environment

Comment: @konkked It was tagged with Java, however Sotiris wrongly edited it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regular expression will match your examples

```
img\/s\/\d+?x\d+?\/
```

the / matches /
the \d matches digits 0-9 and the + means 1 or more. The ? makes it lazy instead of greedy.

the img and s just match that literally

check out https://regex101.com/ to try out regular expressions. It's much easier than testing them by debugging code. Once you find an expression that works, you can move on to make sure your specific code will perform the same.

Comment: You cannot test regex for java in regex101

Comment: it doesn't always work for .net either, but it usually does and it's a good starting point

Comment: For instance, this is specifically for java: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Is your goal to match all three of those cases?

If so, this should work: `img\/s\/\d+x\d+\/`

It searches for `img/s/[1 or more digits]x[1 or more digits]/`